# Screen reader: Read DOM structure then focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a simple web based text adventure which could be played using a screen reader. What I want is that when I navigate to the next page the content is read in DOM structure and then the focus is set to the button. So it should read the title, text and buttons. When I use the screen reader the focus then should be on the first button so that I don't have to navigate through the whole page to get to the button.
Is this possible?

Here is a really simple example of what I have:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, tw-passage, aside, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
}

div, p {
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.contentImg {
  max-height: 50vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  order: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content a {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.content p {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div id="title_Start" class="title">Title</div>
  <div>
    <span class="content">
      <span id="content_Start" class="LANG">
        Text...
      </span>
      <span class="choices">
        <a>Link 1</a>
        <a>Link 2</a>
      </span>
    </span>
      <img class="contentImg" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/detail/233-2332677_image-500580-placeholder-transparent.png"/>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to wrest control away from a user—especially those reliant on assistive tech. Imagine a website that automatically scrolled through text when you landed on it and then moved your mouse to a button. It's not a perfect analogy, since focus often needs to be managed in accessible applications. But I would consider if it's truly needed before proceeding.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code that you provided. The title, text, and links are in the correct reading order. Screen-reader users can `[tab]` through links or access a list of all links on the page without reading through all content. Other than not having `href` attributes in your `a` elements, everything seems to be working as it should in your example. Unless you have a really good reason for setting focus (like a page change in SPA or AJAX reload), then I'd advise against trying to manage focus.

Comment: Perhaps the question comes because of a lack of familiarity of how a screen reader works? Most screen readers have an option to read the page upon loading but that's an option the user should set. I have that turned off because I don't want to hear everything. I want to explore myself. As long as you use semantic HTML (headings, tables, lists, etc) then you're off to a good start for accessibility. Make sure images have `alt` text if they're informative.

Comment: Indeed I don’t really know how screen readers work in detail. But your comments helped me so thanks for that.

Comment: And no worries about the alt attributes. I have them in my real code and only removed them for the example ;)